# test utility function which operatos over chidlren

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I have a component which requires children (called `layout component`). There is also a function inside this component that iterates over children and does something. I want to test this function. So I've extracted this function to separate utility class and give children as parameter. It works well in browser.

But in test I have problem. I don't know how to define and pass children to this utility function.

```
  const children = (
      <div />
      <div />
  );
```

gives me compilation error: "JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)".

Surrounding `div`s with `React.Fragment`

```
  const children = (
    <>
      <div />
      <div />
    </>
  );
```

gives we me only 1 child in my layout component.

I'd like to pass children to the utility function but I don;t know how to define them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
const children = (
  <div />
  <div />
);
```

You can use a real array e.g.:

```
const children = ([
  <div key="0"/>,
  <div key="1"/>
]);
```

Or just use the fragment as you have already figured out.

Comment: FYI: wrapping all in Fragment gives me one child.